# Something is creating strange URLs in Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress, url, web, seo

I have a problem with a Wordpress based website. Something is creating strange URLs. I know about those URLs, because Google Webmaster Developer try to Crawl them and the Crawler gets a 404 error (Not found). I have that problem in different websites:

1. In the first one the URLs looks like spam:
   http://xxxx.com/wp-content/w3tc/apple-iphone-3gs-8gb-black-manual
2. In the other website the URLs make sense based on the content, but they are not valid URLs:
   http://xxxx.com/portfolio/pool-view-suite-bathroom/
3. In other website, it's creating URLs that looks like valid, but with a ".html" in the final

If you try to access those URLs, you will get a 404 error. Curiously, when you look the "Linked By" tan in Google Developer Tools, you will see that is linked by another strange URL o there is no linked from. And that URLs are not in the sitemap, I checked it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the first one is a trojan without a doubt. Quite usually, you'll find them in index.php, footer.php, header.php . If in doubt, check with an online tool like [Sucuri](http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/)

Once you isolate it, it's very important to know how you have it. While most people thinks they have been "hacked", in most cases you uploaded it by yourself from your own computer, so be sure to scan it thoroughly.

About the other cases, sounds more like an htaccess issue, but based on the first case, quite probably it's caused by this trojan as well. Ask your host to check the site, it's in their best interest to do it so. But assuming it's just htaccess, try this: go to Settings --> Permalinks and change the permalinks structure to anything else than what you have now. Don't hit the submit button yet. In the meanwhile, **BACKUP** your htaccess file and then delete it. Hit submit on the permalinks page an a new .htaccess file will be created. Try your site now. If it works, it was just a simple htaccess issue. If not, something else, going from a trojan to a server misconfiguration to anything in between

Comment: Hi, thank you! I scanned the website using Sucuri, it's clean. I check index, header, footer and htaccess, there isn't something strange. I don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the domain was used before and you are seeing past valid urls which are now 404, or maybe these are incorrect, inbound spammy links which you would want to be 404. Duff links can be found anywhere on the internet and so no reason to think your site is generating them.

Comment: But some URLs are so strange and looks like spam. Thank you!

Comment: COuld be the site was hacked before and generated those urls and google is still looking for them - as google would. Without full info, everything is just speculation.

Comment: The problem is that we check the URLs as "fixed" on Google Webmaster Tools but we get new URLs after that.

Comment: That can happen, keep marking as fixed and google will resurface new ones they have found. As long as the generation of the links is a past event (if they were produced by your site) then you have nothing to worry about.